# C# generics and interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

It is possible to implement something like this? I have a problem with this code in the  declaration of class SomeClass.

The exception that I'm receiving is:

> 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SomeClass' does not implement interface member 'WindowsFormsApplication1.IB.SomeGetter'. 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SomeClass.SomeGetter' cannot implement 'WindowsFormsApplication1.IB.SomeGetter' because it does not have the matching return type of 'WindowsFormsApplication1.MyClass'.

My code:

```
public interface IA
{ }

public interface IB
{
    MyClass<IA> SomeGetter { get; }
}

public class A : IA
{ }

public class MyClass<T>
    where T : IA
{ }

public class SomeClass : IB
{
    public MyClass<A> SomeGetter
    {
        get { return new MyClass<A>(); }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: The getter on SomeClass is implementing MyClass<A>, not MyClass<IA>

Comment: You'll need to read up on covariance and contravariance with generics: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

Answer (score 5):

To achieve this you'll need to introduce an interface (`MyInterface`) to make use of [covariance](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/02/16/covariance-and-contravariance-faq.aspx):

```
public interface IA
{ }

public interface IB
{
    MyInterface<IA> SomeGetter { get; }
}

public class A : IA
{ }

public interface MyInterface<out T>
    where T : IA
{ }

public class MyClass<T> : MyInterface<T> where T : IA
{ }

public class SomeClass : IB
{
    public MyInterface<IA> SomeGetter
    {
        get { return new MyClass<A>(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's right. You have to use MyClass<IA> in the getter. That does the job, but you have to work with the interface and cannot use class A.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to introduce an interface for MyClass:

```
public interface IMyClass<out T> where T : IA
{

}

class MyClass<T> : IMyClass<T> where T : IA
{
}
```

Notice the 'out' keyword in the interface. Then you could write

```
public class SomeClass : IB
{
    public IMyClass<A> SomeGetter
    {
        get { return new MyClass<A>(); }
    }
}
```